# Trouble With Python Calculator

Tags: python

I would like to make a maths app for primary school children (children aged 4-11) and I've started by making a calculator. I'm following a YouTube video but it's showing an error. I'm coding in python 3.4.3 by the way.

This is my code:

```
from tkinter import*

def iCalc(source, side):
    storeObj = Frame(source, borderwidth=4, bd=4,bg="pink")
    storeObj.pack(side=side, expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
    return storeObj

def button (source, side, text, command=None):
    storeObj = Button(source, text=text, command=command)
    storeObj.pack(side=side, expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
    return storeObj

class app(Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.option_add('*Font', 'arial 20 bold')
        self.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
        self.master.title('Calculator')


        display = StringVar()
        Entry(self, relief=RIDGE,
                textvariable=display,justify='right' ,bd=30,bg="pink").pack(side=TOP, expand=YES,
                                                                            fill=BOTH)
        for clearBut in (["CE"],["C"]):
            erase = iCalc(self, TOP)
            for ichar in clearBut:
                button(erase, LEFT, ichar,
                       lambda storeObj=display, q=ichar: storeObj.set(''))

        for NumBut in ("789 /" , "456*" , "123-", "0.+"):
            FunctionNum = iCalc(self, TOP)
            for iEquals in NumBut:
                button(FunctionNum, LEFT, iEquals,
                        lambda storeObj=display, q=iEquals: storeObj.set(storeObj.get() + q))

        EqualsButton = iCalc(self, TOP)
        for iEquals in "=":
            if iEquals == '=':
                btniEquals = button(EqualsButton, LEFT, iEquals)
                btniEquals.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>',
                                lambda e, s=self, storeObj=display: s.calc(storeObj), '+')
            else:
                btniEquals = button(EqualsButton, LEFT, iEquals,
                    lambda storeObj=display, s=' %s '%iEquals: storeObj.set(storeObj.get()+s))


            def calc(self, display):
                try:
                    display.set(eval(display.get()))
                except:
                    display.set("ERROR")



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app().mainloop()
```

And this is the error which keeps showing up:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1533, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\sony\Documents\Raeesa Calc.py", line 42, in <lambda>
    lambda e, s=self, storeObj=display: s.calc(storeObj), '+')
AttributeError: 'app' object has no attribute 'calc'
```

What do those errors mean?

Comment: fix the indentation

Comment: Sorry if I sound a little silly, but please could you tell me what the indentation is?

Comment: python uses indentation(spacing) for parsing, and currently `calc` is indented too far (or has too many spaces)

Comment: Okay I'll try that thank you!

Answer (score 3):

s is an **app** object.  Your **app** class does not have a method **calc**.  The only appearance of that name is inside a **for** loop within **__init__**.  If that's supposed to be a class method, you need to pull it left to the proper indentation level: delete enough spaces that it's vertically under "def **init**".

Also, what are you trying to do with this code?

```
 for iEquals in "=":
     if iEquals == '=':
```

The **for** loop has exactly one value in the iteration set, which *must* be an equals sign.  Why do you have a **for** to go through one constant item and then *test* to see whether that's what you have?  A simple line will do the same thing:

```
iEquals = '='
```

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed some of your problems here. In part you're not used to markdown, but you definitely had some errors. See my comments:

```
import ast
# Honestly you should do `import tkinter as tk`,
# but it's not that bad.
from tkinter import *

# this should be named something different,
# maybe something like `wrap_widget`. Also note
# snake_casing instead of camelCasing. Python avoids
# camelCasing, and uses StudlyCase for classes, and 
# snake_casing_for_everything_else.
def iCalc(source, side):
    storeObj = Frame(source, borderwidth=4, bd=4,bg="pink")
    storeObj.pack(side=side, expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
    return storeObj

def button(source, side, text, command=None):
    storeObj = Button(source, text=text, command=command)
    storeObj.pack(side=side, expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
    return storeObj

# Should be `App`. You could also just inherit from `tk.Tk`, which is
# a toplevel window.
class app(Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.option_add('*Font', 'arial 20 bold')
        self.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
        self.master.title('Calculator')

        display = StringVar()
        # Just further wrapped your line
        Entry(self,
              relief=RIDGE,
              textvariable=display,
              justify='right',
              bd=30,
              bg="pink").pack(side=TOP, expand=YES, fill=BOTH)

        # There was no need for looping over single element lists.
        # Also `button_text` is a more accurate name.
        for button_text in ("CE", "C"):
            erase = iCalc(self, TOP)
            button(erase, LEFT, button_text,
                   lambda storeObj=display, q=button_text: storeObj.set(''))

        # row is a better name here, as you're looping over
        # rows of button (texts)
        for row in ("789 /" , "456*" , "123-", "0.+"):
            FunctionNum = iCalc(self, TOP)
            # renamed button_text here, too.
            for button_text in row:
                button(FunctionNum, LEFT, button_text,
                        lambda storeObj=display, q=button_text: storeObj.set(storeObj.get() + q))

        EqualsButton = iCalc(self, TOP)
        # as others have mentioned you really shouldn't loop over the single element string.
        # I'm assuming you plan to add other characters in here. If not,
        # get rid of the extra code!
        for iEquals in "=":
            if iEquals == '=':
                btniEquals = button(EqualsButton, LEFT, iEquals)
                btniEquals.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>',
                                lambda e, s=self, storeObj=display: s.calc(storeObj), '+')
            else:
                btniEquals = button(EqualsButton, LEFT, iEquals,
                    lambda storeObj=display, s=' %s '%iEquals: storeObj.set(storeObj.get()+s))

    # This was indented *way* too much. That's why it wasn't defined.
    def calc(self, display):
        try:
            # I uses `ast.literal_eval`, as there are less security risks.
            # And for maths, there's really no reason to need anything else.
            display.set(ast.literal_eval(display.get()))
        except:
            display.set("ERROR")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app().mainloop()
```